# Why is the difference a negative value?

Tags: java

The idea is to calculate a difference beetwen two times (in milliseconds) where **time2** is in the future. The result should be a positive value because **time2** is in the future. Where is the error?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

String time2 = "23:59:00"; //this time should be in the future

Date date2 = null;

try {
    date2 = sdf.parse(time2);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

long difference = date2.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
System.out.println("difference: " + difference);
```

Comment: `System.out.println(date2);` would have told you the answer.

Comment: When you have a bug, your debugger is often the quickest way to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are are parsing a *time* into a `java.util.Date`, which is an instant in time stored in milliseconds, it is just leaving the date at `Thu Jan 01 23:59:00 1970`, the epoch date but with your time. However `new Date()` gives you the current date, so you get quite a large difference when you compare the two.

For situations like these, *it is good to use a debugger*.

Answer (score 1):

*String time2 = "23:59:00";* is not a date in future. 
Since you are not setting any date components here and only using the time components the default date is set to the date component, which is Jan 01 1970.

So *Jan 01 1970 23:59:00* is not a future date as compared to new Date()(*current date*)

Answer (score 1):

date2 = sdf.parse(time2) returns a date object with starting at the epoch - Jan 1 1970.

new Date gets the time right now

The getTime function gets the number of seconds since  January 1, 1970, so the new Date value will be larger .